# Unnecessary re-render in simple store based router

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I created a simple router that routes solely based on the current state of a single store. The router looks at each of its children, extracts the state it `select`ed and then tests if the route should be shown according to its `when` property.

```
var Router = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const {children, state} = this.props;
    const activeRoute = React.Children.toArray(children).find(when);

    return React.createElement(
      activeRoute.props.component,
      Object.assign(
        {},
        activeRoute.props.select(state),
        {
          setState: this.props.setState,
        }
      )
    );

    function when(child) {
      return child.props.when(child.props.select(state));
    }
  }
});

var Route = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      select: identity,
      when: alwaysTrue,
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    throw new Error('Route should never render');
  },
});
```

These components can be used like this.

```
<Router state={this.state} setState={this.sState}>
    <Route component={Pets} when={this.onPets} select={this.selectPets} />
    <Route component={Home} />
</Router>
```

When using `why-did-you-update`, I found that it is re-rendering unnecessarily. I would like to eliminate these unnecessary re-renders, but am failing to do so. What is causing the re-renders and how can I avoid them?

There is a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/puledet/1/edit?js,output). Click on "See pets (click here)" to see the console fire off a series of avoidable re-render warnings.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `why-did-you-update` is warning us because the `children` property between the two renders is equal, but not the same reference. This happens because we return new `React.createElement`s on each render.

To correct this, I can move `children` into the `this.props`, `this.state`, a property on `app`, or even a global. If I was using an es6 class instead of `createClass`, I could create an instance variable. Using one of these methods, I can pass `children` along in the render method.

```
<Router state={this.state} setState={this.sState} children={routes} />
```

A working example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/puledet/5/edit?js,output).